# IEnumerable FirstOrEmpty Extension

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, covariance

### Problem

I am looking for a way to implement `FirstOrEmpty` for a `IEnumerable<X>` where X implements `IEnumerable<T>`.  Basically, if the predicate does not match anything, return `Enumerable<T>.Empty`.  I do not want to constrain the source parameter to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<X>>` or because I might want to pass in something that implement `IEnumerable<X>` (e.g. `IEnumerable<IGrouping<bool, X>>`).

### Usage Example

```
IEnumerable<T> myCollection;
var groupCheck = myCollection.GroupBy(t => t.SomeProp == 23);

var badGroup = groupCheck.FirstOrEmpty(t => !t.Key);
var goodGroup = groupCheck.FirstOrEmpty(t => t.Key);

foreach(T x in badGroup) { ... }
foreach(T x in goodGroup) { ... }
```

Old way:

```
IEnumerable<T> myCollection = ...;
var groupCheck = myCollection.GroupBy(t => t.SomePropOnClassT == 23);

var badGroup = (groupCheck.FirstOrDefault(t => !t.Key) ?? Enumerable<T>.Empty);
var goodGroup = (groupCheck.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Key) ?? Enumerable<T>.Empty);

foreach(T x in badGroup) { ... }
foreach(T x in goodGroup) { ... }
```

### Attempts

#### Attempt 1:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> FirstOrEmpty<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate) where TSource : IEnumerable<TResult>
{
    TSource tmp = source.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    if(tmp != null) {
        foreach(TResult x in tmp)
        {
            yield return x; 
        } 
    }
}
```

#### Attempt 2:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> FirstOrEmpty<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate) where TSource : IEnumerable<TResult>
{
    TSource tmp = source.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    return tmp == null ? Enumerable.Empty<TResult>() : tmp;
}
```

Comment: Sure would be nice if you selected an answer!

Answer (score 4):

Your own solution:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> FirstOrEmpty<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate
    )
    where TSource : class, IEnumerable<TResult>
{
    return source.FirstOrDefault(predicate) ?? Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();
}
```

is actually working. I only added the `class` constraint. This means "`TSource` must be a reference type", and an interface is OK with a `class` constraint. The reason for this is that `default(TSource)` might not be `null` if `TSource` were some struct. You can call it like this:

```
var badGroup = groupCheck.FirstOrEmpty<IGrouping<bool, T>, T>(g => !g.Key);
var goodGroup = groupCheck.FirstOrEmpty<IGrouping<bool, T>, T>(g => g.Key);
```

Unfortunately, the compiler isn't smart enough to figure out the type parameters itself, so you have to supply them in the angle brackets `<..., ...>` like above. I haven't found a solution for that.

Now, if you always use this with `IGrouping<,>`, you might want to use the following slightly less general method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> FirstOrEmpty<TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TResult>> source,
    Func<IGrouping<TKey, TResult>, bool> predicate
    )
{
    return source.FirstOrDefault(predicate) ?? Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();
}
```

This time it goes like this:

```
var badGroup = groupCheck.FirstOrEmpty<bool, T>(g => !g.Key);
var goodGroup = groupCheck.FirstOrEmpty<bool, T>(g => g.Key);
```

and the good news is that with this approach the compiler *will* infer your type arguments, so:

```
var badGroup = groupCheck.FirstOrEmpty(g => !g.Key);
var goodGroup = groupCheck.FirstOrEmpty(g => g.Key);
```

works.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use a refactored version of Attempt 2:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> FirstOrEmpty<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate) where TSource : class, IEnumerable<TResult>
{
    return source.FirstOrDefault(predicate) ?? Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();
}
```

EDIT: I am curious to know why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: This works but the compiler seems to have a hard time inferring the types parameters.

Comment: @DStanley Any ideas on how to make the compiler more happy?

Comment: Haven't found one yet. Feel free to post as a separate question.

Comment: What happens if `TSource` is a value type, like a struct implementing the interface? Then `FirstOrDefault` can't return null, but will return the "zero" value of that struct. How can `??` operator work then? Maybe it's better to say: `where TSource : class, IEnumerable<TResult>`. In this context, "class" means any reference type (class, interface, delegate type, array type).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Correct. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @DStanley I neglected to add a `class` constraint to the TSource type parameter.  It should compile now.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the same result as @phoog but am having a hard time getting the compiler to infer the type parameters:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> FirstOrEmpty<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate) where TSource : IEnumerable<TResult>
{
    return (IEnumerable<TResult>)source.FirstOrDefault(predicate) ?? Enumerable.Empty<TResult>();
}
```

Best I have come up with is to explicitly state them:

```
var badGroup = groupCheck.FirstOrEmpty<IGrouping<bool,int>,int>(t => !t.Key);
var goodGroup = groupCheck.FirstOrEmpty<IGrouping<bool,int>,int>(t => t.Key);
```

Comment: That will return a `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`.  I want to return the first list or an empty list if the list of lists it empty.

Comment: OK That makes more sense.  I will amend.